# What is the difference between type I error and type II error in default or non-default case?

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors

What is the difference between type I error and type II error in forecasting default of a company? For example, I can set null hypothesis to be "The company will default next year", or I can set it to be "The company will not default next year", so my type I and type II error will be vice versa in this case. Can I set the null hypothesis as I want, or how should I decide what is the null hypothesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you want to reject the null hypothesis so you set it as the case you want to avoid. When reading $p$-values and probabilities, it's easier to interpret the levels you want to define as showing stronger evidence against the null hypothesis, but it is up to what you consider *the outcome you want to avoid or show*.

In your example, I'd write:

$H_0$: "The company will default next year"

$H_1$: "The company will not default next year"

***Type I*** error : Forecasting $H_1$ when $H_0$ is true, also called a false positive

***Type II*** error : Forecasting $H_0$ (or more precisely failing to reject $H_0$) when $H_1$ is true, also called a false negative

You may see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12461/how-to-specify-the-null-hypothesis-in-hypothesis-testing) for another example.